# Using map to pluck from nested list

Tags: r, purrr, pluck

I'm trying to familiarize myself with `purrr`, `map` and `pluck` and I have a deeply nested list:

```
test_list <- 
    list(
      outer_1 = list(
        list(
          inner_1 = list(pluck = "String I Want", dontpluck = "other string")
        )
      )
    )
```

```
$outer_1
$outer_1[[1]]
$outer_1[[1]]$inner_1
$outer_1[[1]]$inner_1$pluck
[1] "String I want"

$outer_1[[1]]$inner_1$dontpluck
[1] "other string"
```

And I'd like to extract `"String I want"`

I know I can get the string using

```
test_list$outer_1[[1]]$inner_1$pluck
```

But I'd like to abstract this using map but I'm missing some steps. (mainly I don't know how to emulate the `[[1]]` part using `map` - something like:

```
map(test_list, "outer_1") %>%
  map("inner_1") %>%
  map("pluck")
```

## Desired Output

```
[1] "String I want"
```

Comment: your list has a depth of 4 but you have only three levels ie, `outer_1`, `inner_1` and `pluck`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:

```
map_chr(pluck(test_list, "outer_1"), pluck, "inner_1", "pluck")

[1] "String I Want"
```